# x509Certificate - Save a binary signature in pkcs#7 format (.net c#)

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I am signing some data with a self signed `X509Certificate` in c#. Signature results as a binary `byte[]`. I want to save this signature to a `pkcs#7` format file with extenstion `.p7b`. When I save this using `FileStream` as required. It generates an invalid `p7b` file.

Can anyone help save this signature as a valid external file? Or point out if there is something wrong with the approach?

// EDIT: Adding the code as asked by `Eugene Mayevski`

```
// Open Store Location & fetch certificate
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
X509Certificate2Collection certifcates = store.Certificates;
X509Certificate2 certificate = certifcates[0];`

// fetch private key
string publicKeyString = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

// get binary of data & sign it.
byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Sample data to sign. Although it would be a document.");
byte[] signature = privateKey.SignData(buffer, new SHA1Managed());
```

Comment: Did you have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?
You do not want to store the certificate but the signature, right?

Comment: Yes, I need to store signature itself. I have gone through the link you've provided. I think these functionalities are encapsulated in .net 4.0 as the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography.pkcs` is not available. Anyways the data is being signed & verified. Only thing i want is to store the Signature in a proper file format.

Comment: It would be great to see the code you use to create a signature in the first place. It can be that you don't actually create a PKCS#7 signature, hence the problem.

Comment: Hi Eugene Mayevski, I've edited the message to include the code.

Comment: @Ram what makes you think that `RSACryptoServiceProvider` returns the cryptographic message syntax (CMS) defined in (the older) PKCS#7 standard?

Comment: @owlstead I first admit to be a new-bee for cryptography & certification. I would be obliged, if you can guide me for the correct approach if it's a matter of few lines of code OR to quantify the efforts if not. My goal is to sign a document & save the signature file in pkcs#7 format for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not generating a Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) message format which is defined in PKCS#7. You generate just the signature, which can be placed in the *container format*.

To create a CMS formatted message yourself, please take a look at the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180946%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or use the [C# version of Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I could digest this after digging further into cryptography (as I said I am new to it). The API pointed in the documentation link is a bit confusing also as it shows the .net version upto 3.0 & these classes are not accessible until security dll is added. Hence giving a feel that it is Obsolete. @BatteryBackupUnit I didn't understood your comment due to this.